# Plot vertical lines in matplotlib within a given y range

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, visualization

I'm using the following:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))

ax.set_ylim(bottom=0, top=10)
for i in range(4):
    ax.axvline(x=i, ymin=5, ymax=9, color="red", linewidth=40)
```

Which gives:

[image]

I would expect there to be a vertical line at each point from `y = 5` to `y = 9`.

Comment: See the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline.html) for the values `ymin` and `ymax` expect. Use [`vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.vlines.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.vlines) instead of `axvline`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [**`matplotlib.pyplot.vlines`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.vlines.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.vlines), as suggested by BigBen in the comment:

```
for i in range(4):
    ax.vlines(x=i, ymin=5, ymax=9, color="red", linewidth=40)
```

[image]

Comment: You are right, updated the answer, thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the parameters for axvline, you see that ymin and ymax goes from 0 to 1.  A fraction of your complete ylimit.
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvline.html

So you need something like .5 to .9 or calculate the appropriate fractions.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))

ax.set_ylim(bottom=0, top=10)
for i in range(4):
    ax.axvline(x=i, ymin=.5, ymax=.9, color="red", linewidth=40)
```

Output:

[image]